# Need excel formula to extract a single or double digit number preceding a character or symbol

Tags: string, text, excel-formula, extract

Here's the case I have a column with a number of text strings. Each string contains either a single or double-digit number followed by either an "x" or the words " set" or " rounds." I'm trying to extract the numbers preceding the "x" or the words. Here's an example:

| string | Desired Outcome |
| --- | --- |
| jump 3x10 | 3 |
| push 10x3 | 10 |
| pull 3 sets 10 times | 3 |
| pull 3 rounds 8 times | 3 |
| push 10 times 3 sets | 3 |

I've tried FIND, SEARCH, {1,2,3,4, 5, 6,7, 8, 9} only to over-complicate this. There has to be a simple way to locate these combinations (##&"x", "## sets" or ""## rounds") and extract the related numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume "String" data housed in Column A1:A6 with header.

In "Outcome" `B2`, formula copied down :

```
=LOOKUP(9^9,0+RIGHT(LEFT(A2,MIN(SEARCH({"x"," sets"," rounds"},A2&"x sets rounds"))-1),ROW(A$1:A$250)))
```